# Update keras.json on Google Colab

Tags: keras, theano, google-colaboratory

I tried to update `keras.json` on Google Colabs, but its throwing UnsupportedOperation error

[image: Keras Theano update]

Is there any other alternative to achieve this?

Comment: I'm getting the `No such file or directory: '.keras/keras.json'` error. Could you share how you overcame with this?

Comment: @talha06 - I never had such issue. Probably try re-installing tensorlfow or any relevant package...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening the file as readonly -- pass `'w'` to the `open` call on line 9. ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open))