# How to find keras.json file in google colab?

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory, tf.keras

On my local system I know where is the keras.json file present(.keras/keras.json) but when I switched to google colab, I don't know where to find it.

I did google search for this problem but have not got any answer. I went through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083075/update-keras-json-on-google-colab) but got nothing helpful.

Any reply and reference will be appreciable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can find that file in colab ~/.keras/keras.json

[image: Colab image for reference]

Good post to dynamically switch backend https://stackoverflow.com/a/44446822/8660575